# ExtJS: Clear a data binding from a viewController

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, binding

I am using the admin-dashboard template and made the following modification to the MainController:

```
routes: {
        ':node': {
            before : 'checkSession',
            action : 'onRouteChange'
        }
    },
```

Thus, when I change a route the `before` route will happen first, so the following method will first get called and then the routing will proceed onward:

```
checkSession : function() {
        var args   = Ext.Array.slice(arguments),
            action = args[args.length - 1],
            hash = window.location.hash;

        // TODO: use hash to clear patient header when appropriate

        if (hash.indexOf('#new-patient') > -1) {
            console.log(hash);
        }
        action.resume();
    },
```

This works splendidly. However, when I get the condition of `hash.indexOf('#new-patient') > -1` I would like to clear a comboBox that I have defined in a view as:

```
bind: {
      store: '{patients}'
  },
  reference: 'patientCombo',
```

This is from a view in the same scope as the above method from the viewController is, that is they are both in the hierarchy of the same viewModel. I am just not sure exactly how I can clear this from the above method. I just want to set the combo box back to no selected value (if one had been selected) and then update the bindings. Merci!

Comment: `this.lookupReference('patientCombo').setValue('');`

Comment: It appears that `this` is referring to the controller object and is thus throwing this error:
`checkSession — MainController.js:37TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.lookupReference('patientCombo').setValue')`

I had tried variants using component queries, all to no avail.

Comment: lookupReference is a ViewController method (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewController.html#method-lookupReference), so the problem here is that your combo is not being found and then you are trying to setValue() of a null reference.
Can you try setting up a fiddle so I can take a look at your code?

Comment: I'm trying ComponentQuery again. If I can't get it, then I will make a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried using Ext.ComponentQuery, I initially referenced the itemId, but the xtype was wrong (the combobox and displaytext, among other sundries are in a container). Since this is the only combobox in my app now, I just tried it as:

```
combo = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox')[0]

            if (combo){
                combo.setValue('')
            }
```

and, lo' and behold, it worked!